# Associate CSV file to my app to be opened from main and messages?

Tags: ios, csv, cfbundledocumenttypes

I am building an iOS app that handles contacts.
I want to let the users the option to import CSV files to the app.

Read many tutorials + this answer:

[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

As I understand now I need to define the file type in the Documents type section, and thats what I did.

Still, when I open an email with CSV file in it, it just let me preview the file and dose not suggest to open it in my app.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Check the answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22968706/1463604